# Many Buttons on a Page, Need to send back Unique Post Data with each

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm listing out a bunch of cars with a button next to them that when clicked will need to perform a GET but also sends over that item's model.Name:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetCarUrl", "Car", FormMethod.Get, new { model = Model }))
{
    if(Model.Cars != null && Model.Cars.Count > 0)
    {       
        foreach (CarContent car in Model.Cars)
        {
            <p>@car.Name</p>
        }

            <input type="button" value="Get Car Url" class="submit" />
    }
```

So the page renders a bunch of hyperlinks and buttons:

```
[hyperlink1] [submit]
[hyperlink2] [submit]
[hyperlink3] [submit]
[hyperlink4] [submit]
[hyperlink5] [submit]
...
```

When a user clicks on any of the submits, I need to pass back its corresponding @car.CarType for that specific hyperlink

Not sure how to go about this.  My action method expects a @car.CarType for that specific car hyperlink to be sent to it

**UPDATE**

Here is my markup:

```
    Html.Hidden("userId", Model.UserId);
    Html.Hidden("lessonId", Model.LessonId);

@if(....)
{
    foreach (Car car in Model.Cars)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("GetFileDownloadUrl", "Car", FormMethod.Get, new {  carFileUrl= car.CarFileUrl}))
        {
                <p><a href="/Car/@Model.CarId/@Model.UserId/Url">@fileContent.Name</a>
                    <input  type="submit" value="download" name="downloadFile"/>
                </p>
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the action method it's to hit, wanting to send in the userId, CarId, and carFileUrl:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetFileDownloadUrl(string carFileUrl, int carId, int userId)
{
    string downloadUrl = string.Empty;
    downloadUrl =GetDownloadUrl(carId, carFileUrl, userId);

    return downloadUrl;
}
```

Here is my route:

```
context.MapRoute("CarFileDownload", "Car/{carId}/{userId}/{carFileUrl}", new { controller = "Content", action = "GetFileDownloadUrl", carFileUrl= UrlParameter.Optional, carId = UrlParameter.Optional, userId = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

When I click a button, it's not posting back to my GetDownloadUrl actionmethod.

I don't know if I just don't have the route setup right in terms of if I need all those optional params set and then in my BeginForm do I need to specify all of them again or not since I have some of them as hidden fields being posted back?  Not sure why it is not hitting my GetFileDownloadUrl action method in this case...

Comment: Don't use a form with a submit button, just have hyperlinks, then generate your urls so that they look like:

    http://mydomain/GetCarUrl?CarType=MyCarType

Comment: I don't want that.  My Url is going to be long and complicated because I'm sending over a filepath as one of the params.  Plus I don't want to exspose everything in a url every time.

Comment: per my updated code (see UPDATE), I am not postive I am doing this right.  Setting up my route correctly with specifying the BeginForm anonymous method (the new{}) and then I think I don't need the ampersands inside my if statement has one which starts the entire code block... so I am unsure of a lot of things here on my setup/syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Have a hidden field for the car type, and use JQuery or similar to make the click event of the hyperlink set the car type hidden field.

Using the concept of 'progressive enhancement' you can make you page still function for those users who may not have javascript enabled - simply make the links actually do the get and make the button hidden.  Then, using JQuery, override the default behaviour of the link (as described above) and make the button visible.  That way you will get your desired behaviour, but your page will still function for those without javascript.

Comment: "simply make the links actually do the get" - how?  what do you mean?  Links can't postback

Comment: so in other words use a hidden button for enabled javascript user and when clicking the hyperlink it somehow updates the hidden button and somehow triggers the button to be clicked?  Then if they don't have javascript enabled, the buttons will show.  We don't care about them not having JS enabled, nobody cares about that anymore...that was a worry 5 years ago.

Comment: I meant make your actions support GET so that the links will work - if you don't care about users with JS disabled, then don't worry about it.

Comment: I didn't mean a hidden button, rather a hidden field.  Hidden fields have a value, which the default MVC model binder works fine with.  You can set it's value with JQuery using something like  `$('#CarType').val('Toyota');`

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing preventing you to create many forms in one page.

```
if(Model.Cars != null && Model.Cars.Count > 0)
{       
    foreach (CarContent car in Model.Cars)
    {
        <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("GetCarUrl", "Car", FormMethod.Get, new { model = car }))
        {
            <p>@car.Name</p>
             @Html.Hidden("CarId", car.Id)
             <input type="submit" value="Get Car Url" class="submit" />
        }
        </div>
    } 
}
```

note that each form `model = car`

Comment: model is not of type Car.  So I don't get why you did model = car when the Model is called CarViewModel.cs.  Car is just a CarContent instance found in the Cars list property in my CarViewModel

Comment: Hmm, tried this but it's not submitting the form when I click a button

Comment: *edited* the button's type should be "submit" `<input type="submit" value="Get Car" class="submit" />`

Comment: Updating the original post, it's not hitting my action method, just reposting to the same page I'm on already.